# sort a dropdown list with added atrribute or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I am working on a site where I do not have access to the `perl` generated options of a drop down list. The drop downs are populated dynamically and not all options are available to all users.

The code I am able to work with is shown here.

```
<select class="fielddrop" name="PRIMARY_POS" size="1" style="width: 187px;" ></select>
```

#### PRIMARY_POS

populates each option that is able to be selected.

The actual output as seen when the page renders is

```
<select class="fielddrop" name="PRIMARY_POS" size="1" style="width: 187px;">

<option value="0">None Selected
<option value="155935">Option4
<option value="155934">Option3
<option value="155905">Option2
<option value="155933">Option1
<option value="155932">Option5   

</select>
```

What I need to be able to do is set a sort order based on a hidden attribute that is assigned based on the text value

So in the above example. I need the drop downs ( Important as their are mulitple drop downs on the page ) to be able to be sorted by a not yet created attribute

So that the above code might then be

```
<option value="0">None Selected
<option sortvalue="5" value="155935">Option4
<option sortvalue="4" value="155934">Option3
<option sortvalue="3" value="155905">Option2
<option sortvalue="2" value="155933">Option1
<option sortvalue="1" value="155932">Option5     

</select>
```

The sortvalue being set base don the Text value of the option select. So that a sortvalue of 5 would be assign to Option4. Just a smaple as the text will need to be assigned.

End result should be that the Drop down list now has a custom attribute of Sortvalue and the select drop down is now sorted by that value.

Once again, I can not directly change the attributes but can manipulate the results. Hope that was easy to follow, which I doubt :/

Comment: "which I doubt" - you have truly suggested. Why does a sortvalue of 5 should be assigned to Option4 ? What is the logic?

Comment: The reason is the need to be able to sort this option list based on values other then those in the option groups already populated information.Using the value attribute is not a valid sorting method for the needed output. Also, the use of an alphabetical li8st is not the correct sort as well.

Comment: Scale all this text down do what the parameters are for setting the `sortvalue`. That is not clear. Also not clear what you intend to do with that attribute after

Comment: The sortvalue needs to be conditional based on the Text in the drop down. I believe that part was made clear.  "The sortvalue being set based on the Text value of the option select. So that a sortvalue of 5 would be assign to Option4. Just a sample as the text will need to be assigned.          The sortvalue attribute then would be used to sort the dropdown list. That was the entire purpose for assigning the sortvalue as mentioned.

Comment: But there is no relationship between that text and sort values shown. You have `Option5=1` and `Option4=5` ... no matching reference there

Comment: Hence why I said that the sortvalue needs to be conditionally based on the value in the drop down list. So the text within the option text itself would be used to assign the sortvalue. There is a definitive list of options. So I need to be able to create a way to assign and sort this list based on that list. "So that a sortvalue of 5 would be assign to Option4. Just a smaple as the text will need to be assigned." is the relationship I am asking to be created. The text could be Sample Item, the code would need to relate that to the sort value of the position I wish to assign to it.

Comment: OK..so you need a hashmap and a way to read hashmap to do assigning

Comment: Not sure if I understand your needs, but check my answer. I've created an example that sorts by a custom field (in this case, data-sort-value) and puts the reordered <options> back in the select list.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object where the keys are the text and values are sort order. Then loop over options and add attribute based on that map

```
var optsMap = {
  "Option4": 5,
  "Option5": 1
   ......
};

var $select =  $('select[name=PRIMARY_POS]')

$select.find('option').attr('data-sortvalue', function(){
   return optsMap[$(this).text()] ||0;      
}).sort(function(a,b){
    return +($(a).data('sortvalue')||0) - +($(b).data('sortvalue')||0);
}).appendTo($select);
```

You can then read the value using:

```
$select.change(function(){
   alert($(this).find(':selected').data('sortvalue'));
})
```

If all you are needing is sorting and don't need attribute can remove one step

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gctegqzv/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Ok, though I see the demo working it does not seem it will work in my environment. Do I need to indicate which drop down this should be applied to in some manner?

Comment: Is based on initial selector used for `$select`. Note that demo uses very generic selector .. answer is more defintiive

Answer (score 0):

Common practice is to prefix those "added attributes" with `data`. You could try something like this with jQuery, if I'm understanding you correctly.

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/30cvudz8/7/

```
<select class="my-select">
    <option data-sort-value="3" value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option data-sort-value="5" value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option data-sort-value="4" value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option data-sort-value="1" value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option data-sort-value="2" value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>



var optionList = new Array();
$('select.my-select option').each(function() {
    optionList[optionList.length] = $(this).attr('data-sort-value')+'::'+$(this).val();
});
optionList.sort(); // sort it 
var newOptionList = '';
for(var i = 0; i < optionList.length; i++) {
    // recreate option
  var parts = optionList[i].split('::');
  newOptionList += '<option value="'+parts[1]+'" data-sort-value="'+parts[0]+'">Option '+parts[1]+'</option>';
}

// wipe and repopulate the select list
$('select.my-select').html(newOptionList);
```

To add an attribute (like data-sort-value) after you have a select list, you can do something like this:

```
$('select.original option').each(function() {
    var sortingValue = getSortingValueFromText($(this).text());
    $(this).attr('data-sort-value', sortingValue);
});
```

Comment: Maybe I am following the answer incorrectly. However the example posted has the data-sort-value already populated. I need a way to actually create the mapping between the items and then insert that data-sort-value into the html prior to being able to sort it. So it seems you have shown me the best way to sort the actual data-sort-value, I still need a valid way to have that code added to each option with no direct way to ad it into option choices.

Comment: @David you said in question that you had no access to the perl code that generates options and that the attribute needed to be created. This is getting even more confusing now

Comment: I'm not sure what your algorithm is for determining sorting value from option text (since it's not alphabetically), but I've updated with another example, assuming you already have your getSortingValueFromText() function defined, it should work.

Comment: I do not have access to the perl that creates it. I do know every possible option that can be listed though. That is why I said I need a valid way to link the options ( map) them. Where did I insinuate I have access to the perl for this?

Comment: Thank you Danl looking it over. Thanks in advance for the help, this has been a huge pain.It seems as though between yours and charlietfl 's answers, it is a partial solution. Seeing the other answer, I can see that I need to be able to create a map as they specified.

Comment: Basically the html needs to start without the data-sort-value="3" and then have it assigned using a map, then the data value inserted and the sort then processed. Trust me I realize this is not the idea environment for this. I have been searching for an way to do this and trying various options for days. I finally decided reaching out here might prove beneficial